# remove transparency from color but keep color itself

Tags: r, colors

I would like to remove transparency from a color but keep the color itself.

E.g. I like the transparent version of green, but i want this color without transparency.

```r
library(scales)
show_col("green")
```

[image]

```r
alpha("green",0.3) -> nice_green
show_col(nice_green)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I thought about using `lighten` from `colorspace` but I get different greens.

```r
library(colorspace)
library(scales)
lighten("green",0.3) -> not_green_I_want
show_col(not_green_I_want)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to check all of the named colors that have "green" in the name to see if one will suffice:

```
colors()[grep("green", colors())]   # Forty green colors
```

A better solution would be to shift to hue/saturation/value color specification. This looks close to what you want, but could probably use some tweaking:

```
show_col(hsv(121/360, .4, 1))
```

See the manual page `?hsv` for details.

Comment: Something like `ch <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb("green")); newcol <- hsv(h=ch["h",], v=ch["v",], s=0.3)` seems to do it, so I think the hsv adjustment is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail! Is there also a solution for greys? I moved the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582936/remove-transparency-from-grey-but-keep-grey-itself) since some might consider grey not as a color :D