# remove transparency from grey but keep grey itself

Tags: r, colors, transparency

I recently learned [how to remove transparency from a color but keep the color itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74525675/remove-transparency-from-color-but-keep-color-itself):

```r
library(scales)


# approach for colors
show_col("green")
```

[image]

```r
# make light transparent green
alpha("green",0.3) -> transparent_green

# keep the light green but remove transparency
ch <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb(transparent_green))
nontransparent_green <- hsv(h=ch["h",], v=ch["v",], s=0.3)

#compare greens
show_col(c(transparent_green,nontransparent_green))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

however, this does not work for greys:

```r
library(scales)

# aprroach for grey
show_col("grey10")
```

[image]

```r
# make light transparent grey
alpha("grey10",0.3) -> transparent_grey

# keep the light grey but remove transparency
ch <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb(transparent_grey))
nontransparent_grey <- hsv(h=ch["h",], v=ch["v",], s=0.3)

#compare greys
show_col(c(transparent_grey,nontransparent_grey))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this little function which should work irrespective of the starting colour.

```r
de_alpha <- function(col) {
  col <- col2rgb(col, alpha = TRUE)
  alpha <- col[4,]
  col <- col[1:3,]
  whiteness <- (255 - alpha)/255
  do.call(rgb, as.list((col + (255 - col) * whiteness)/255))
}
```

This works on green giving the same result:

```r
transparent_green    <- scales::alpha("green", 0.3)
nontransparent_green <- de_alpha(transparent_green)

scales::show_col(c(transparent_green, nontransparent_green))
```

[image]

But also works on your grey example:

```r
transparent_grey    <- scales::alpha("grey10", 0.3)
nontransparent_grey <- de_alpha(transparent_grey)

scales::show_col(c(transparent_grey, nontransparent_grey))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: So this is roughly the reverse of the function `scales::alpha` .

Comment: BTW,  better not to name your variable `alpha` . I know R will distinguish it from the function,  but it's ugly :-)

Comment: I wasn't the person who posed the question.   I may be more OCD than you; I just prefer never to use the name of an existing function as a variable name for clarity

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it's a good principle to stick to.